# How to equally distribute generator object to multiple list

Tags: python

I created generator for list of million of items not to exhaust memory, now in order to process then I want to equally distribute those items into multiple lists:

for example:
sample code:

```
from itertools import islice

batch_size = 500

def get_ob():
    for i in range(20000000):
        yield i


obj = get_ob()
x = []
counter = 1
while True:
    objects = list(islice(obj, batch_size))

    if not objects:
        break
    x.append(objects)
```

It took a long to create these multiple lists. Is there any better approach for this. Please suggest.

Comment: You're still going to exhaust your memory if you're appending each `objects` "sublist" to the `x` list.

Comment: @jfaccioni okay.. true.. the actual scenario is to pass batch_size of values to a method.. calling methods multiple times using multithreading to make it fast but islice itself is slow.

Comment: @Pradeep, `islice()` is not slow, it just returns iterator which you're converting to list *(which could possibly be slow)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght, yes my bad. that's correct converting it to list is slow.. what is the better way to store/handle this.

Comment: @Pradeep, it's not always true. You've mentioned that you need to process this chunks multiple times which is definitely not the best case for iterators.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Yes, so there would be multiple objects of chunks for eg. x1 = [1,2,3...n] x2 = [n+1, n+2, .... n+m] etc... and wanted to pass these x1, x2.. xn objects to same function one by one.. I can use multithreading for this but dividing these chunks itself takes a long time.